# Assembly loading failure when using the CLI library

Tags: c++, c++-cli

For some reason I can not launch my 64-bit application. I receive an error:

```
14:17:41:587 Error: The type initializer for 'Va.MBClient.Program' threw an
 exception.

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
r 'Va.MBClient.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundExce
ption: Could not load file or assembly 'CGateCliAdapter.dll' or one of its depen
dencies. The specified module could not be found.
   at Va.MBClient.Program..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Va.MBClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Oleg\projects\Va.M
BClient\Va.MBClient\Program.cs:line 87
```

Somehow this is connected with my CLI DLL file, because when I outcomment the line `private static CGateCliAdapterMain cliAdapter = new CGateCliAdapterMain();`, which refer to the CLI library, I can launch the application.

I do see this in Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

I've tried to use `fuslogvw` to catch a binding failure, but it can't catch it for some reason! So now I don't know how to troubleshoot the problem.

I've used [Dependency Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) and have found that the following files are missing:

```
MSVCR110.DLL
GPSVC.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
MF.DLL
MFPLAT.DLL
MFREADWRITE.DLL
WLANAPI.DLL
```

---

I've tried to copy `wlanapi.dll` directly to a folder with the application and that helped (the DLL file disappeared from the missing list), but why are DLL files not visible when I've installed *Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012*? I've tried to reinstall and repair the installation.

Also, I can't find the DLL files `MSVCR110.DLL` and `MSVCP110.DLL`.

I don't know why. I've tried to reinstall Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 many times.

---

Update:

Now again I can not run my program for some reason! After one day, Dependency Walker again claims that DLL files are missing. However, I do have "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012".

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) needs to be installed.

Comment: probably it never worked probably i just used another rdp window by accident a day ago